# How to set height auto css div follow data?

Tags: css

.....................................................................................................................................................................

i want to set height auto of div follow data , how can i set ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<div style="
width: 100%;
">
    <div style="
                margin: 0;  
                padding: 0; 
                height: 48px;    
                outline: 0;  
                font-weight: inherit;  
                font-style: inherit;  
                font-size: 100%;  
                font-family: inherit;  
                vertical-align: baseline;
                background: #f5f5f5;
                border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
                width: 100%;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                display: block;

">
        <div style="
                    margin: 0 auto;  
                    width: 992px; 
                    height: 48px;
        ">
            <div style="
                        margin-top: 0px;  
                        height: 48px;                
                        text-align: center;
                        float: left;
                        width: 100%;
                        line-height: 48px;
            ">    
                <div style="
                        margin-top: 0px;  
                        height: 48px;                
                        text-align: center;
                        float: left;
                        line-height: 48px;
                        width: 50%;
                ">      
                    kkkkkkkk
                    <br>
                    kkkkkkkk
                    <br>
                    kkkkkkkk
                    <br>
                    kkkkkkkk
                </div>

                <div style="
                        margin-top: 0px;                  
                        text-align: center;
                        float: right;
                        line-height: 48px;
                        width: 50%;
                ">
                    kkkkkkkk
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use inline styles when you are using classes ? And what is the question again ?

Comment: i want to set height of div follow my data ?

Comment: @user3169443 That makes no sense, try again. Think what you want and explain it in terms we can understand. What height do you want to set? Do you mean if you input data in the `div` the height will auto?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want. Not 100% sure as you have not made much sense.

I started by making a `id` for each of your div because having that much inline styling is just silly.

### HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <div id="innerdiv2">
            <div id="innerdiv3">
                <div id="innerdiv4">Testing
                    <br />Test info
                    <br />Test info
                    <br />Test info</div>
                <div id="innerdiv5">Testing</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#innerdiv {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: block;
}
#innerdiv2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 992px;
    height: auto;
}
#innerdiv3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 48px;
}
#innerdiv4 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 50%;
}
#innerdiv5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Now what you are looking for (I think) is `overflow: hidden;` You are floating the inner divs so there height wasn't being counted in the parent `div`. Adding the `overflow` to `#innerdiv` solves this problem.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5Ne9Y/)

Comment: Again not sure what you mean. If you want a fixed height just up the height E.G: `height: 300px;` If you want it auto you will have to use `overflow: hidden;` Because you are using `float` the height isn't being counted by the parent (due to the float) so it wouldn't wrap around anything. `overflow: hidden;` stops that from happening and wraps the inner divs.